# Error in initializing tree view type mismatch

Tags: vb6

I am using VB6 for coding.

In that i am using tree view.

I have below code :

```
Dim rptNode             As Node
Dim intTemp             As Integer
Dim intRpts             As Integer
Dim strSQL              As String
Dim rsTreeItems         As ADOdb.Recordset
Dim rsReports           As ADOdb.Recordset

    '~~~~~~~~To remove error handling, remove code between tildes~~~~~~~~~
    On Error GoTo Initialize_TreeView_ErrorHandler
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    tvwRpts.LineStyle = tvwTreeLines
    tvwRpts.Nodes.CLEAR
    'add root node

     Set rptNode = tvwRpts.Nodes.Add(, , "Root", "Reports")
    Set rsTreeItems = New ADOdb.Recordset
    Set rsReports = New ADOdb.Recordset
```

This code gives me error for line:

```
 Set rptNode = tvwRpts.Nodes.Add(, , "Root", "Reports",1)
```

It states that :

```
error in initializing tree view type mismatch
```

When I add watch to it, it just gives :

```
<key is not unique in collection>
```

Please help me.

Comment: @Mort yeah..true thing.. but unfortunately i am not the owner or decision maker regarding this application :(

Comment: The `Node` class may be from a different library than the `Treeview`'s one. Try to define `rptNode` as `Variant`. Or look for the fully qualified names in object explorer (`SomeMSLib.Node)`.

Comment: I think that's it: the Node definition used does not match the TreeView used.  Try properly qualifying the declaration, e.g. `Dim rptNode As ComctlLib.Node` or `Dim rptNode as MSComctlLib.Node` as appropriate.